# Replace link-ending of specific URLs

Tags: php, url, replace

I want to change the URL-ending of specific links in my parsed html. In previous occasions I used this code

```
$html = file_get_html('URL');
// search for .htm change to .php
foreach ($html->find("td a") as $a) {
    $a->href = substr_replace($a->href, 'php', -3);
```

But it would change all links. I have now to differentiate between specific URLs. I only want to to change those links, which **don't** contain "box" in its link.

```
Example:
thisismyboxlink123.htm --> no change of ending please
thisismyotherlink123.htm --> thisismyotherlink123.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`strpos()`](https://php.net/strpos) to check if the string `"box"` is inside the link. If not (`===false`), you can replace it:

```
$html = file_get_html('URL');
// search for .htm change to .php
foreach ($html->find("td a") as $a) {
    if (strpos($a->href, 'box') === false) {
        $a->href = substr_replace($a->href, 'php', -3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.